How to apply the wordSpacing to the PDF
I need to apply the wordSpacing (Tw) to the PDF, but it doesn't work because the PDFBox library encodes the text and the U+0020 symbol does not appear in the PDF.
How can we avoid this behavior and apply the wordSpacing parameter via PDFBox library?
my code:
try (PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(
                pdf,
                page,
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,
                false,
                true)
        ) {
            stream.saveGraphicsState();
            stream.setFont(font, fontSize);
            stream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
            stream.beginText();
            stream.newLineAtOffset(100, 100);
            stream.setWordSpacing(50);
            stream.showText("HELLO WORLD");
            stream.endText();
            stream.restoreGraphicsState();
}

how it looks in the PDF
BT
  78.3975 777.75494 Td
  50 Tw
  (\000+\000\(\000/\000/\0002\000\003\000:\0002\0005\000/\000') Tj
ET


According to the PDF spec:

Word spacing shall be applied to every occurrence of the single-byte character code 32 in a string when using a simple font (including Type 3) or a composite font that defines code 32 as a single-byte code. It shall not apply to occurrences of the byte value 32 in multiple-byte codes.

According to your example you appear to use a font with a double-byte encoding (Identity-H?) which does not define code 32 as a single-byte code. Thus, word spacing does not apply.
If you want to use word spacing, you need font encodings that are single-byte or mixed with the single byte 0x20 representing the space glyph.

The issue arises because the stream.showText() method in the PDFBox library automatically applies encoding to the text. This encoding replaces the standard space character (U+0020) with encoded glyphs. Since wordSpacing (Tw) only affects the spacing of the actual U+0020 space character, it has no effect when encoded glyphs are used.
To address this and properly apply wordSpacing, you can manually split the text at spaces and insert them into the content stream separately. This allows the wordSpacing parameter to function as intended.
Here is the corrected version of your code:`try (PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(
pdf,
page,
PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,
false,
true)) {
stream.saveGraphicsState();
stream.setFont(font, fontSize);
stream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
stream.beginText();
stream.newLineAtOffset(100, 100);
stream.setWordSpacing(50);

// Split text at spaces and write each part with spacing applied
String text = "HELLO WORLD";
String[] words = text.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    stream.showText(words[i]); // Add the word
    if (i < words.length - 1) {
        stream.showText(" "); // Add a space to let wordSpacing apply
    }
}

stream.endText();
stream.restoreGraphicsState();

}
`

did you test that it works as intended? The javadoc gives a different explanation: "This will have an effect only with Type1 and TrueType fonts, not with Type0 fonts (...)"
